# How to create separate layout and drwawable folder for Note2?

Tags: android, layout, screen, drawable, resolution

I know Note2 size is same as xlarge, but screens in the note2 device is totally mess up and at the same time it is perfect in other xlarge phones like s3.

I don't understand whether note2 takes images from wrong folder or layout from wrong folder.

Please, somebody help me to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of note2 is actually 320. thats why problem occured. so you have to make a **layout-sw360dp** folder for note2 because **360dp** converted to pixels at **320dpi** is **720px**.

Comment: Thanks @Segi let me check.